# Is not a subtype of type Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

im trying to fetch a news api and display the data in my widget, but im getting this error: _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => Article' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')

this is the function where i fetch the data

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../models/article_model.dart';

const url =
    "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=br&apiKey=399c0c22d7c845608909937a974ab209";

Future<List<Article>> getArticle() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<Article> articles =
        data.map((json) => Article.fromJson(json)).toList();
    print(articles);
    return articles;
  } else {
    throw Exception("Failed to get articles");
  }
}
```

this is the model i create to receive an article:

```
class Article {
  final String title;
  final String author;
  final String description;
  final String url;
  final String urlToImage;
  final String content;

  const Article({
    required this.title,
    required this.author,
    required this.description,
    required this.url,
    required this.urlToImage,
    required this.content,
  });

  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(
      title: json['title'],
      author: json['author'],
      description: json['description'],
      url: json['url'],
      urlToImage: json['urlToImage'],
      content: json['content'],
    );
  }

  get article => null;
}
```

that`s my widget:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
    
    import '../models/article_model.dart';
    
    class ChamadaSuite extends StatelessWidget {
      final Article article;
      final String title;
      final String author;
      final String description;
      final String url;
      final String urlToImage;
      final String content;
    
      const ChamadaSuite(
          {super.key,
          required this.title,
          required this.author,
          required this.description,
          required this.url,
          required this.urlToImage,
          required this.content,
          required this.article});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 110,
                height: 90,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  image: const DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover, image: AssetImage("assets/vasco.png")),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        "ESPORTE",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          height: 1.2,
                          letterSpacing: 0.13,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        article.title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          height: 1.4,
                          letterSpacing: 0.16,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }


and this is my homepage.dart, where i call the function to populate the widget:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import '../api/get_article.dart';
import '../models/article_model.dart';
import '../widgets/manchete_suite_destaque.dart';
import '../widgets/chamada_suite.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Tab> tabs = [
    const Tab(child: Text('últimas notícias')),
    const Tab(child: Text('bahia')),
    const Tab(child: Text('política')),
    const Tab(child: Text('esportes')),
    const Tab(child: Text('últimas notícias')),
    const Tab(child: Text('agenda cultural')),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Article>> fetchArticles() async {
    return await getArticle();
  }

  final article = const Article(
    author: '',
    content: '',
    description: '',
    title: '',
    url: '',
    urlToImage: '',
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leadingWidth: 100,
          leading: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
            child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/ibahia.svg'),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            ),
          ],
          bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(30),
              child: TabBar(
                indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: tabs,
              )),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Article>>(
          future: fetchArticles(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Article article = snapshot.data![index];
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          const MancheteSuiteDestaque(),
                          ChamadaSuite(
                            title: article.title,
                            author: article.author,
                            content: article.content,
                            description: article.description,
                            url: article.url,
                            urlToImage: article.urlToImage,
                            article: article.article,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            } else {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can i solve this error? i dont even know where its the error

Answer (score 0):

Specify a type when calling `map` method, for example: `map<Article>`.

In your code, change:

```
List<Article> articles = 
  data.map((json) => Article.fromJson(json)).toList();
```

To:

```
List<Article> articles = 
  data.map<Article>((json) => Article.fromJson(json)).toList();
```

By the way, depending on your Dart version, you may be able to write this instead:

```
List<Article> articles = 
  data.map<Article>(Article.fromJson).toList();
```